# How to compare the input statement with the mood list like if I entered I am fine in input?

Tags: python

```py
mood = ['Fine', 'bad', 'good', 'sad', 'angry']
a = input("how are You  ").split()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the list and compare each element:

```py
moods = ['fine', 'bad', 'good', 'sad', 'angry']
mymood = input("how are You  ").strip()

for mood in moods:
    if mymood == mood:
        break
else:
    raise ValueError("I can't tell your mood")
```

But there are better ways in Python. You can use the containment operator, `in`.

```py
if mymood not in moods:
    raise ValueError("I can't tell your mood")
```

Even better if `moods` was a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

```py
moods = {'fine', 'bad', 'good', 'sad', 'angry'}

# The test looks exactly the same, but will be faster for large sets.
if mymood not in moods:
    raise ValueError("I can't tell your mood")
```

After that, the `mymood` variable is known to be one of the moods.